# segment based url not working codeigniter

Tags: url, codeigniter-2, segment

at this site:

http://www.syriadailynews.com/sdn/

I used codeigniter with segment based url

and it works fine at localhost (xampp)

but after uploded the site, all urls not working

this is my .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
```

Comment: are you sure you have auto loaded the url helper

Comment: yes I'm sure, and I moved the script to:
http://syriadailynews.com

Comment: try printing `$this->uri->segment_array();`

Comment: this result of printing it is:
Array ( )

Answer (score 0):

I edit config.php to this:

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

It's worked now !  ^_^